# How to apply a "for loop" in all columns in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, multiple-columns

I have this data and a *for* that I created to convert all the elements in a column, based on condition (if). (I know that there are more ways to do that...)

Here it is:

```
S1 <- c(0,1,1,0,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,0)
S2 <- c(2,1,0,1,0,2,1,1,0,1,2,2,1)
S3 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,2,0,1,2,1,2,0,2)
S4 <- c(2,1,0,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,0)

df <- data.frame(S1,S2,S3,S4)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(df[i,1] == 0){
    df[i,1] <- "A/A"
  }
  if(df[i,1] == 1){
    df[i,1] <- "A/T"
  }
  if(df[i,1] == 2){
    df[i,1] <- "T/T"
  }
  if(df[i,1] == "NaN"){
    df[i,1] <- 0
  }
}
```

This is the actual:

```
S1  S2  S3  S4
0   2   0   2
1   1   1   1
1   0   0   0
```

When I run the *for* it works for the first column only, since I described the `df[i,1]`. The question is, how can I do this for all columns simultaneously?
Is there a way I could solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A surprisingly interesting question that raises many issues.

Well, if really all you want to do is replace a value in a dataframe with some other value, no matter where it appears, you can just use the `[<-` function directly and avoid all looping and equivalent constructs:

```
df[df==0] <- "A/A"
df[df==1] <- "A/T"
df[df==2] <- "T/A"
df[df=="NaN"] <- 0
```

I would caution that there is an enormous amount of type conversion magic going on here! After the first assignment, all the columns are changed from numeric to character. And yet all the subsequent comparisons still work, because the following are all `TRUE` in R:

```
1 == "1"
"1" == 1
```

This can be a dangerous way to code. If you really want to know if two objects are exactly the same you would use the following, which evaluates to `FALSE`:

```
identical(1, "1")
```

It's also curious that you have the condition `x == "NaN"` in your code. That's fine for detecting the *string* `"Nan"` but if you actually want to detect an IEEE 754 "not a number" value you would actually have to use the `is.nan` function.

If you actually want to know how to apply any sort of function to all columns of a data frame, see the other answers to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I think I was overthinking things. In this case I actually knew beforehand that I would not have "NaN" values in my data. I just put there to kind of have a model for next time that I would not be sure of it. "is.nan" would be what I'd use.

Answer (score 5):

use `sapply` to iterate over columns and then apply logical comparison with `==` for finding and replace.

```
sapply(df, function(x){
  x[x==0] <- "A/A";
  x[x==1] <- "A/T";
  x[x==2] <- "T/T";
  x[x=="NaN"] <- 0;
  x
})
```

this produces:

```
      S1    S2    S3    S4   
 [1,] "A/A" "T/T" "A/A" "T/T"
 [2,] "A/T" "A/T" "A/T" "A/T"
 [3,] "A/T" "A/A" "A/A" "A/A"
 [4,] "A/A" "A/T" "A/A" "T/T"
 [5,] "A/A" "A/A" "A/T" "A/T"
 [6,] "T/T" "T/T" "T/T" "T/T"
 [7,] "T/T" "A/T" "A/A" "T/T"
 [8,] "A/T" "A/T" "A/T" "A/T"
 [9,] "A/T" "A/A" "T/T" "T/T"
[10,] "A/T" "A/T" "A/T" "A/T"
[11,] "A/T" "T/T" "T/T" "T/T"
[12,] "A/T" "T/T" "A/A" "T/T"
[13,] "A/A" "A/T" "T/T" "A/A"
```

If you want to replace `df` and keep the data.frame structure, then use `lapply`

```
df[,] <- lapply(df, function(x){
  x[x==0] <- "A/A";
  x[x==1] <- "A/T";
  x[x==2] <- "T/T";
  x[x=="NaN"] <- 0;
  x
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use `mutate_all` and `case_when` from package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(case_when(. == 0 ~ 'A/A',
                            . == 1 ~ 'A/T',
                            . == 2 ~ 'T/T',
                            . =="NaN" ~ '0')))
    S1  S2  S3  S4
1  A/A T/T A/A T/T
2  A/T A/T A/T A/T
3  A/T A/A A/A A/A
4  A/A A/T A/A T/T
5  A/A A/A A/T A/T
6  T/T T/T T/T T/T
7  T/T A/T A/A T/T
8  A/T A/T A/T A/T
9  A/T A/A T/T T/T
10 A/T A/T A/T A/T
11 A/T T/T T/T T/T
12 A/T T/T A/A T/T
13 A/A A/T T/T A/A
```

Comment: That worked.. I prefer not using a package though. Thank you!

Comment: Ha ha - I wouldn't call 'dplyr' just *a package* - it is a re-invention of how one can use R in a data analysis environment. While it can be overused (witness the silly "backlash" against it) most questions here merit have "the dplyr answer" in addition to any others.

Comment: Oh yeah, I agree with that!

Answer (score 1):

Consider also vectorized nested `ifelse` across a block of columns (no apply/for loops):

```
df[,1:4] <- ifelse(df[,1:4]== 0, "A/A", 
                   ifelse(df[,1:4]==1, "A/T", 
                          ifelse(df[,1:4]==2, "T/T", 
                                 ifelse(is.na(df[,1:4]), 0, NA))))
df

#     S1  S2  S3  S4
# 1  A/A T/T A/A T/T
# 2  A/T A/T A/T A/T
# 3  A/T A/A A/A A/A
# 4  A/A A/T A/A T/T
# 5  A/A A/A A/T A/T
# 6  T/T T/T T/T T/T
# 7  T/T A/T A/A T/T
# 8  A/T A/T A/T A/T
# 9  A/T A/A T/T T/T
# 10 A/T A/T A/T A/T
# 11 A/T T/T T/T T/T
# 12 A/T T/T A/A T/T
# 13 A/A A/T T/T A/A
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in your questions:

- `"NaN"` cannot exist in your data, because columns are of type `numeric`, I'll assume you meant `NaN`.
- `0` cannot exist in your output because columns will be of type `character`, I'll use `NA` instead, but you could use `"0"` if that's what you want.

The kind of issue you're having makes me think you should probably be using factors, at least it make the conversion really easy :

```
df[] <- lapply(df,factor,c(0:2,NaN),c("A/A","A/T","T/T",NA))

#     S1  S2  S3  S4
# 1  A/A T/T A/A T/T
# 2  A/T A/T A/T A/T
# 3  A/T A/A A/A A/A
# 4  A/A A/T A/A T/T
# 5  A/A A/A A/T A/T
# 6  T/T T/T T/T T/T
# 7  T/T A/T A/A T/T
# 8  A/T A/T A/T A/T
# 9  A/T A/A T/T T/T
# 10 A/T A/T A/T A/T
# 11 A/T T/T T/T T/T
# 12 A/T T/T A/A T/T
# 13 A/A A/T T/T A/A
```

If you really want to get characters in the output and not factors you can use this:

```
df[] <- lapply(df,function(x)
  as.character(factor(x,c(0:2,NaN),c("A/A","A/T","T/T",NA))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the for loop?

```
for (j in 1:4){
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
        if(df[i,j] == 0){
            df[i,j] <- "A/A"
        }
        if(df[i,j] == 1){
            df[i,j] <- "A/T"
        }
        if(df[i,j] == 2){
            df[i,j] <- "T/T"
        }
        if(df[i,j] == "NaN"){
            df[i,j] <- 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the way I was going for.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `mapvalues` function from the plyr package with either `lapply` or `sapply`

```
library(plyr)
df <- sapply(df, function(x){
  mapvalues(x,from  = c(0,1,2, "NaN"), to = c("A/A", "A/T", "T/T", 0))
})
```